# Should a package not rely on transitive Depends: directive for data.table methods?

Tags: r, data.table

When a package A depends on data.table transitively via another package B which has a `Depends: data.table` directive, the methods of data.table are not recognised in package A.  This appears - at least superficially - to differ from other packages.

Example: a package pkgB has the following which expresses dependency on data.table and zoo directly in the `Depends` directive (n.b. no reason for choosing zoo, it is just used as an example of the behaviour I expect):

DESCRIPTION

```
Package: pkgB
Version: 0.1
Depends: data.table, zoo
RoxygenNote: 6.0.1
```

functions

```
f11 <- function() {
  print(is.data.table(data.table(x)))
  print(data.table(X=x)$X)
  print(data.table(X=x)[,.(X)])
}

f12 <- function() {
  print(index(zoo(x)))
}
```

The output for `f11()` and `f12()` - not shown for brevity - is as expected ie the methods `.` for data.table and `index` for zoo are recognised and no error results.

A second package pkgA has the following which expresses dependency on data.table and zoo indirectly via dependency on pkgb:

DESCRIPTION

```
Package: pkgA
Version: 0.1
Depends: pkgB
RoxygenNote: 6.0.1
```

functions

```
#' @export
f21 <- function() {
  print(is.data.table(data.table(x)))
  print(data.table(X=x)$X)
  print(data.table(X=x)[,.(X)])
}

#' @export
f22 <- function() {
  print(index(zoo(x)))
}
```

Now the following is a console session for a short script, which shows that f21 generates an error because in f21 the data.table function `.` is not recognised, whereas in f22 the zoo function `index` is recognised. search() shows both packages on the path, and in f21 the function `data.table` is recognised, unlike function `.`.

```
> x <- 1:2
> f21()[]
[1] TRUE
[1] 1 2
Error in .(X) : could not find function "."
> f21
function() {
  print(is.data.table(data.table(x)))
  print(data.table(X=x)$X)
  print(data.table(X=x)[,.(X)])
}
<environment: namespace:pkgA>
> 
> f22()
[1] 1 2
> f22
function() {
  print(index(zoo(x)))
}
<environment: namespace:pkgA>
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"         "package:pkgA"       "package:pkgB"      
 [4] "package:zoo"        "package:data.table" "package:stats"     
 [7] "package:graphics"   "package:grDevices"  "package:utils"     
[10] "package:datasets"   "package:methods"    "Autoloads"         
[13] "package:base"      
> 
> devtools::session_info()
Session info ------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       Rgui                        
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United Kingdom.1252 
 tz       Europe/London               
 date     2018-03-18                  

Packages ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 package    * version  date       source        
 base       * 3.4.3    2017-12-06 local         
 compiler     3.4.3    2017-12-06 local         
 data.table * 1.10.4-3 2017-10-27 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 datasets   * 3.4.3    2017-12-06 local         
 devtools     1.13.5   2018-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 digest       0.6.15   2018-01-28 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 graphics   * 3.4.3    2017-12-06 local         
 grDevices  * 3.4.3    2017-12-06 local         
 grid         3.4.3    2017-12-06 local         
 lattice      0.20-35  2017-03-25 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 memoise      1.1.0    2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 methods    * 3.4.3    2017-12-06 local         
 pkgA       * 0.1      2018-03-18 local         
 pkgB       * 0.1      2018-03-18 local         
 stats      * 3.4.3    2017-12-06 local         
 utils      * 3.4.3    2017-12-06 local         
 withr        2.1.1    2017-12-19 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
 zoo        * 1.8-1    2018-01-08 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
>
```

Is this correct behaviour?  It is certainly possible I do not understand how these transitive dependencies are handled, or perhaps the different status of `zoo::index` and `data.table::.` but at first sight they are behaving differently is the zoo method is loaded via a transitive dependency, whereas the data.table method is not.

There is nothing special about the use of `zoo` package in this example, it is only providing a context for a question about `data.table`.

There is nothing special about the function `.` in this example, the same goes for `:=` for example.

In the functions I am referencing the variable x in the global environment.  This would I believe normally be a deprecated style, but in the case of large data.table objects it is I believe normal.

I rely on transitive dependencies quite a lot and so far have had it work as expected, avoiding repetition etc.  Should I kick this habit?

This is a minimal example derived from a more complex application.  It is still quite long, and I'm not sure if a gist or somesuch would make this question more useful or digestible - guidance appreciated.

Comment: Usually you should use Imports instead of Depends.

Comment: Agree with Roland. AND ... if your package uses any function from `data.table`, then it too should `Imports: data.table` and not rely on the upstream dependency to ensure its installation; first, because you still need namespace visibility of its functions; second, because the upstream pkg might remove the dependency and leave you hanging. But mostly the first.